# Was Adam aware of his other part before separation?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, creation, adam

> וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹקים אֶת־הָאָדָם ... זָכָר וּנְקֵבָה בָּרָא אֹתָם׃
>
> And God created man in His image, ... male and female He created them. ([Gen 1.27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.27?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.1.27.3&lang2=bi))

Rashi brings Midrashim:

> But according to a Midrashic explanation, He created him at first with two faces, and afterward He divided him. (Genesis Rabbah 8:1 and see Eruvin 18a)

Adam was very upset not having a spouse and was very happy to meet one after G-d split them apart (acc. to that Midrash). That implies he wasn't aware of his other half.

Why, weren't they symmetrical, wasn't the other, feminine, part alive and talking? What did Adam think his back was?

Comment: Midrashim is not meant to be taken littery. According to Rambam, only fools read them at face value. Adam was born naturally, with a father and a mother like you and me.

Comment: @Turk Hill what father and mother? The Torah says explicitly that HaShem directly created Adam.

Comment: The “Garden of Eden” story is a parable.

Comment: @Loani See Rambam.

Comment: @turkhill you keep saying things are parables, but any time somebody asks questions on those parables you try to shut them down.  What's the point of parables if not to ask questions in order to understand them better?

Comment: @Heshy What on earth are you talking about? I always share my information when people ask questions. I answered a lot of questions lately and if lo ani asked for the metaphor I'd be happy to share.

Comment: @Heshy and lo ani: The "Garden of Eden" story is about morality and intelligence, and the duty and obligation to develop one's intelligence. The Rambam felt that the Garden of Eden parable taught a person how to live life correctly because the Torah is certainly holy, he felt that no other book - and I agree with him - tells a man how to live life correctly.

Comment: @Loani The Rambam sees the Tree of "good and evil" in the parable not as a distinction from right and wrong but from truth and falsehood. Meaning, that people should evaluate every situation, determine the best course of action, and act intelligently, not morally because morality is only a set of rules for the general public who needs to be told how to act in any given situation, but is by no means conventional.

Comment: @turkhill If that story is a parable, what other stories are parables? How far in the Torah do you go?

Comment: @user9806 You do not have to agree with all of my thinking, but I am convinced that a lot of the Torah is made up of parables. For example, Noah's flood, the tower of Babel, and Akedah are parables designed to teach moral lessons. However, I still believe Abraham existed. These are the interpretations according to rationalists like Maimonides, Ralbag, and ibn Ezra.

Answer (score 2):

I refer you to Ch. 2 verse 20:

> וַיִּקְרָ֨א הָֽאָדָ֜ם שֵׁמ֗וֹת לְכָל־הַבְּהֵמָה֙ וּלְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וּלְכֹ֖ל חַיַּ֣ת הַשָּׂדֶ֑ה וּלְאָדָ֕ם לֹֽא־מָצָ֥א עֵ֖זֶר **כְּנֶגְדּֽוֹ**׃‏

After assigning names to all creatures, Adam found no helpmate **facing him**.

The monkey had a Mrs. monkey to scratch his back; the cow could send the bull to find fodder for the calves.

But 2-faced Adam was alone; it doesn't say he didn't have a female counterpart, it says he couldn't see his soulmate face-to-face.

(Possibly in order to prevent him from wondering why he needed to deal with a soulmate; "Why couldn't I be created perfect, with an inborn ability to procreate?" So he was created so and discovered that he prefers to have a separate "better half".)

Comment: I'm confused, nobody faced him I agree but did the parts talk to each other, were they aware of each other, because G-d talked to them both.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that Yetzir Kapo would be _blissfully unaware_  of his backpack. But he only had an hour or 2 to deal with "her" - שעה ראשונה הוצבר עפרו, ...ה' עמד על רגליו, ו' קרא שמות, ז' נזדוגה לו חוה - and during that time he was very busy discovering and naming the animals. (And there wasn't a whole lot to talk about, besides for the weather...)